# How to fix maven plugin errors on jenkins?

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins-plugins

I'm setting up a maven project on Jenkins, and I tried to build it, but I got errors on

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) on project BankSystem: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /Users/lilyli/Documents/IntelliJ-wrokspace/BankSystem/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.lily.project.AppTest.xml -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to update the pom.xml file by adding dependencies about

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I also attached java JDK version on the plugin:

```
<plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Can I get any hints to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Maven problem. Please remove the unnecessary dependencies you added.

Instead, the file cannot be deleted. It might be used by another program that is still running or the user in Jenkins might not have the rights to do it.